# Azure Active Directory Blockers - Policy Behaviors

Tags: azure-active-directory

Customer has moved into Azure AD and needs clarification on two behaviors he is seeing in order to broadly roll out to organization and get off prem.

1-  Right now , they have “keep me signed” in configured in Azure AD, however they have shared devices - iPad – in retail stores where they don’t want that behavior and want people to log in every time for websites. Is there a way to set a subgroup of users that keep me signed in will not apply to? Right now they only see a policy setting to configure it on or off for entire organization.

2-  Customer turned on self-service password reset portal, how they only see option to configure what options they have to authenticate to be across whole org. Can they set up different options for different groups of users on what is needed to reset password and confirm identity - retail does q&a - business does authentication, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to Q1:

KMSI is controlled via the company branding, and is not on a per-user, but on a "per-language" (because you can have different branding for different locales). In that sense KMSI cannot be controlled on a per-user basis.

Answer to Q2:

SSPR has 3 states - None, Selected, All. When you choose `Selected` you can chose a single security group for which SSPR will be enabled. All other users will not have SSPR enabled.